# Passing folder path as variable cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to scan a folder whose path is defined by user input & finally apply ffmpeg to store all media files information into a text file. The following code does not work

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /P "path=Enter folder path: "
dir %path% /B /O:N | findstr ".wmv$ .mpg$ .mkv$ .mpeg$ .mp4$ .avi$" >filename.txt
echo. >info.txt
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('type filename.txt') do (
set in=%in%%%a
ffprobe "%path%!in!" 2>>info.txt
)
pause
```

However if I strip user input as follows the code does work?

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
::set /P "path=Enter folder path: "
dir d:\Trainers\out\outt\ /B /O:N | findstr ".wmv$ .mpg$ .mkv$ .mpeg$ .mp4$ .avi$" >filename.txt
echo. >info.txt
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('type filename.txt') do (
set in=%in%%%a
ffprobe "d:\Trainers\out\outt\!in!" 2>>info.txt
)
pause
```

The above script is placed in the folder containing ffprobe.exe & it successfully creates two txt files in the same directory
Note that `d:\Trainers\out\outt\` is the directory to scan for media files & not the directory from where this bat file is executed
The basic syntax for ffprobe is

```
ffprobe "videofile"
```

Comment: Windows environment variables are not case sensitive.  Don't use %path%.  That aside, you're sure that the variable is getting the value you expect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a different variable name than path.

`PATH` already does something really important.  So important, in fact, that your changing it is precisely why the script is breaking.

More specifically, when you try to execute a program using just a filename (no path at all), if the program cannot be found in the working directory, the contents of the `PATH` environment variable are searched.  I haven't seen the error message you're getting, but it's probably failing to execute findstr, which is an executable typically found in a folder specified in `PATH`.

Comment: @nightcrawler: for a list of other variables you shouldn't use, pull up a command prompt and issue the command `set`.

Comment: wow! there is a lot of info hardware info there...quiet useful. Such invisible commands I don't know about :( would you like t suggest some book for me. Ido know a lot about Javascript & webcoding but not about this

Answer (score 1):

The user input command looks like the wrong context. Drop the quotes and it should work properly. The quotes are not needed to separate your prompt from your user input.